# Is it worth it to trim a graph as desired before applying a Dijkstra algorithm on that?

Tags: time, graph, dijkstra

I am using Dijkstra algorithm in a program. Suppose I have a graph with vertices and edges. If we imagine all the edges starting from source vertex **"a"** are as below

```
a-->b        
a-->c   and  
a-->d
```

and all the edges ending to vertex **"f"** are:

```
b-->f
m-->f
e-->f
w-->f
```

what I need to know from the beginning is that, I want the edge **a-->b** as my starting edge (assume **"a"** as start point) so do not need to search for the other neighbors of **"a"** i.e. `(a-->c and a-->d)`

Also I only want the paths which end to **m-->f** (assume **"f"** as the destination) i.e. I do not want the path containing `b-->f,m-->f,e-->f,w-->f`

So is it a good idea to trim my initial graph as such it doesn't contain these edges and then apply Dijkstra on that?

Actually finding these edges needs some searches. I wonder if it is worth (considering time or CPU usage) doing  searches and trimming my graph or there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just search for a path from `b` to `m` then and add the edges you want after that? If you really need it, you may add a special case to exclude edges containing `a` and `f` from ever being added to the stack -- you'd have to check if that makes it faster overall, my bet is that it will on small graphs but not on really huge ones (it only changes speed by a constant factor anyways).